# Three nested summations

Tags: linear-algebra, summation

I'm not sure of how to solve three nested summations and I came up with the following. Is it wrong?

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2i+j} {1}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^n(2i+j)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(2in+\frac{n(n+1)}{2})=3\frac{n^2(n+1)}{2}$$

Comment: It is perfectly correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This summation is perfectly fine, since:

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2i+j} {1} = 2i+j$$

Then:

$$\sum\limits_{j=1}^n2i+j = 2in + \sum\limits_{j=1}^nj = 2in + (\frac{n(n+1)}{2})$$

Then:

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n2in + (\frac{n(n+1)}{2}) = (\sum\limits_{i=1}^n2in) +n\frac{n(n+1)}{2} = 2n\frac{n(n+1)}{2} + n\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

As desired

Answer (score 0):

Since 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n i=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n j=\frac{n^2(n+1)}2$$
we can do this:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^{2i+j}1=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n(2i+j)=3\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^ni=\frac{3n^2(n+1)}2\quad\blacksquare$$